# Something better than gif anims in Google Slides?

Tags: google

I'm being forced from Power Point to Google Slides. I typically create in Adobe CC then import to Power Point but, with the forced move to Google Slides, nothing but an 8-bit gif anim seems to be supported.

I've started looking at LottieFiles from After Effects as an option but short of embedding code (which Slides handles poorly), it looks like gif anims are my only supported output choice.

Does anyone know of something better than gif anims that are supported by Google Slides?

Comment: Google slides supports APNG (animated PNG) images, Perhaps try that.

Comment: Slides purposefully limits the amount of customization you can add. So GIF or APNG are your only options for this sort of thing